# Fully transparent select option box

Tags: css

In my template i have background image and form with select option box, I want to make whole select option box transparent so that user can see the background image in select option box also, I tried the below code but it is not working, Can any one guide me in right direction?

*Demo code*

```css
body{
  color:#fff;
}
  .content{
    min-height: 400px;
    background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/twe_background-1920x1080.jpg');
  }

select{
  background-color:#000; 
  -moz-opacity:.40;
  opacity:.40;
}

select option{
  background-color: #000;
  filter:alpha(opacity=40);
  -moz-opacity:.40;
  opacity:.40;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Content heading.</h1>
    <p>Content body</p>

    <select class="form-control">
    <option>lorem lipsum</option>
    <option>lorem lipsum</option>
    <option>lorem lipsum</option>
    <option>lorem lipsum</option>
    <option>lorem lipsum</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, what you're looking for cannot be done with inbuilt css. The css of the `select` can be changed, but the css customization for the `select option` is limited to `background-color` and `color` and maybe a few more. This is because the styling for option is handled by the browsers.

But as always, you can use a jquery plugin that emulates the select box. And then go crazy with customization. A very good plugin is [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

Opacity will make an element and all it's child elements opaque, wrap your opaque content in a div element with class name 'background', apply background image to that - then apply opacity the class 'content'.

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
}

.content {
  -moz-opacity: .40;
  opacity: .4;
}

.background {
  min-height: 400px;
  background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/twe_background-1920x1080.jpg');
}

select {
  background-color: #000;
}

select option {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="background">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Content heading.</h1>
      <p>Content body</p>

      <select class="form-control">
    <option>lorem lipsum</option>
    <option>lorem lipsum</option>
    <option>lorem lipsum</option>
    <option>lorem lipsum</option>
    <option>lorem lipsum</option>
  </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I can not see the transparency in drop down

Comment: Oh I see, That's going to be a little more tricky. I'd recommend creating a custom select/drop-down rather than overriding each browsers default output.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question.

One approach is to set the background-color with the alpha-value to 0:

```
select {
    background-color: #0000;
}
```